# GribBagLayout gridx, gridy, gridwidth, gridy, fill

Tags: gridbaglayout

I tried a simple test program on GridBagLayout, gridx,gridy, gridwidth, gridheight, and fill values.

The program intends to display 4 buttons,

btn 5 at (0,0) wd 4 ht 1

btn 6 at (0,1) wd 12 ht 4 fill the width 12 and height 4

btn 1 at (4,0) wd 8 ht 1 fill the width of 8

btn 2 at (0,5) wd 1 ht 1

But the actual result on screen is :

[image: Result when running the program]

btn 5 at (0,0) wd 4 ht 1

btn 6 at (0,1) wd 12 ht WRONG fill the width 12 and height NOT FILLING

btn 1 at (4,0) wd 8 ht WRONG fill the width NOT FILLING

btn 2 at (12,0) instead of (0,5)

I am not sure what went wrong in my program, can anyone help ?

Below are the coding

public class t extends Frame {

```
GridBagLayout gbl = new GridBagLayout();
GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();

public t() {
    addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter(){
        public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {  
                System.exit(0);
        }
    });
    setBounds(20,20,500,500);
    setVisible(true);
    setLayout(gbl);
    Button b1 = new Button("B1");
    Button b2 = new Button("Button TWO");
    Button b5 = new Button("Button FIVE");
    Button b6 = new Button("Btn 6");

    c.gridx = 0;
    c.gridy = 0;
    c.gridwidth = 4;
    c.gridheight = 1;
    add(b5,c);

    c.gridx = 0;
    c.gridy = 1;
    c.gridwidth = 12;
    c.gridheight = 4;
    c.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
    add(b6,c);

    c.gridx = 4;
    c.gridy = 0;
    c.gridwidth = 8;
    c.gridheight = 1;
    c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
    add(b1,c);

    c.gridx = 0;
    c.gridy = 5;
    c.gridwidth = 1;
    c.gridheight = 1;
    c.fill = GridBagConstraints.NONE;       
    add(b2);
}

public static void main(String[] args){
    t  test = new t();
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

I made some correction to the original codes on set constraints, below are the codes:

```
    c.gridx = 0;
    c.gridy = 0;
    c.gridwidth = 4;
    c.gridheight = 1;
    c.weightx = 0.250;
    c.weighty = 0.167;
    c.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;       

    add(b5,c);

    c.gridx = 0;
    c.gridy = 1;
    c.gridwidth = 12;
    c.gridheight = 4;
    c.weightx = 1;
    c.weighty = 0.66;
    c.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;

    add(b6,c);

    c.gridx = 4;
    c.gridy = 0;
    c.gridwidth = 8;
    c.gridheight = 1;
    c.weightx = 0.75;
    c.weighty = 0.167;
    c.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;

    add(b1,c);

    c.gridx = 0;
    c.gridy = 5;
    c.gridwidth = 1;
    c.gridheight = 1;
    c.weightx = 0;
    c.weighty = 0.167;
    c.ipadx = 25;
    c.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;       

    add(b2,c);

    setVisible(true);
```

[image]

The output is what I desire.